# Is reciting Qur'an like Yasser Al-Dossari, Nasser Al-Qatami, etc, forbidden of makruh?

Tags: tajweed

I heard from an Ustaz (may Allah preserve him) that madd is only one sound (sawt), and it is wrong to play with the sound (by making the sound higher or lower while making madd), like that of Yasser Al-Dossari ([listen to his madd from here](https://youtu.be/ZnRTF0VwX9Y)). This is surprising because Yasser is the imam of the Al-Haram. But does that make it haram or makruh to make madd like him?

Comment: I don't know what your Ustaz actually says or means -assuming you understood him correctly-, but I don't see anything wrong with the recitation. IMO answering questions by evaluating video- or audio- files is somewhat off-topic. Also IMO all necessary information should be included in the question and external links usually are not helpful for this purpose.

Comment: It means that when someone does madd, he should keep it one sound, without playing with it (by making the sound lower or higher while doing madd). This has *also* been stated by Ustaz Ayman Swayd. Watching the video isn't necessary to answer the question.